# Is it still possible to set default script template for Unity Mac?

Tags: unity, c#, configuration

I want to setup/update the default template(s) for C# scripts in my games.

According to the docs https://support.unity.com/hc/en-us/articles/210223733-How-to-customize-Unity-script-templates on Mac I should be able to go to:

`Applications/Unity/Editor/Data/Resources/ScriptTemplates`

And modify the templates within... however I don't have any "Editor" folder inside my `/Applications/Unity` folder (2020.3.8f1)

Has this moved to a new location? or has my install become corrupt and I need to re-install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you installed your Unity Editor via Unity Hub, and if yes, then the path has changed to this

`/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.11f1/Unity.app/Contents/Resources/ScriptTemplates/`

It may be in `/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Resources/ScriptTemplates/` if so, you will need to use the context menu (2-finger press on touchpad) to expand further into the `Unity.app` package.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, this is a bit closer, I do have an `/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/` folder, but it is completely empty :-(

Comment: Find your Unity (2020.3.8f1) install path and then try `/Contents/Resources/ScriptTemplates`
If not then try `/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Resources/ScriptTemplates`

Comment: you're awesome, it was in the latter `/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Resources/ScriptTemplates/` folder... but I missed this as my 'double tap' to expand 'Unity.app' was just launching the app, I needed to '2 finger press' on the touchpad to show the context menu and choose `Show Package Contents` to navigate deeper into that folder structure.

Comment: thanks man, really happy to help you out
yes, I forgot to mention the thing about `Show Package Content`  
but glad you figured it out
Keep up the good work 